# python: if row[1].upper().find(brand)!=-1:

Tags: python

are these two statements equivalent?

```
if row[1].upper().find(brand)!=-1:
```

and

```
if row[1].upper().find(brand):
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they aren't equal. In Python, any nonzero number is treated as being True, so the second statement will be considered true if the expression evaluates to -1, and false if the expression evaluates to 0 (when it should be true).

Use the first statement.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, no those statements are not equivalent.  However, when you only need to find *if* the substring exists and not *where*, I prefer the `in` operator rather than `.find()`, e.g.:

```
if brand in row[1].upper():
```

This is equivalent to the first statement, but more concise and easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The first one will evaluate to `false` only  if `find()` returns `-1`.

The second one will evaluate to `false` only if `find()` returns `0`.
This even would give you wrong results as `0` means that the substring was found at the beginning of the string. So this statement would evaluate to `false` if the substring is at the beginning and `true` if it was not found.

Answer (score 2):

To explain what the `find()` method does:

```
>>> "hello".find("l")
2
>>> "hello".find("he")
0
>>> "hello".find("x")
-1
```

`-1` is a "magic value" for "search string not found". Contrast this with `index()`:

```
>>> "hello".index("l")
2
>>> "hello".index("he")
0
>>> "hello".index("x")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

Personally, I prefer `index()` because usually, magic values are frowned upon in Python whereas exception handling is the Pythonic way to do it - "EAFP" (it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission).

In your case it looks like the "LBYL" programming style (look before you leap), although you're not showing much context so I don't know what the `if` statement is deciding.

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not.

The first one checks if the result is `-1` and the other one checks if the result is anything which Python regards as "false". `-1` is not regarded as false by Python.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer is correct.  But I find it easier to read `in` than to use numeric results.  I.e.,

```
>>> row
[[1, 'lysol']]
>>> brand
'Lysol'
>>> brand.upper() in row[0][1].upper()
True
>>>
```

Although, once the "Schlysol" brand shows up, all bets are off.  Hm.